# how can the schema processor modify the instance document?

Tags: xml, xsd

http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#Intro:

> When an attribute is declared with a default value, the value of the
>   attribute is whatever value appears as the attribute's value in an
>   instance document; if the attribute does not appear in the instance
>   document, the schema processor provides the attribute with a value
>   equal to that of the default attribute.

Does anyone know what does it mean for the "schema processor to provide the attribute with a value" ?

isn't the schema just a validating mechanism with no output? if so how can the schema processor modify the instance document?

What does it mean for a schema to set a value when it is just a validating document with no output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a schema processor validates a document, it collects information about elements and attributes into a post validation schema infoset (PSVI). The PSVI and the instance document are two different things, but of course closely related. PSVI can be used by applications to provide additional information on the document and its content model. For example, a DOM implementation can use the PSVI to return the default attribute value if one is missing, as well as reporting if that was the case, i.e.

```
boolean Attr#getSpecified()
```

Comment: do you mean to say that if my only purpose for my schema is simply to validate my instance document, the `default` keyword would practically be useless?

Comment: No, I don't see how that follows from my explanation. default means that there may be a value, but if it's absent the default should be used. Applications must be prepared to handle an absent value. They may receive it from the parser, but not necessarily.

Comment: Yes, if the only output you want from the schema processor is "yes it's valid" or "no it isn't", then specifying a default value for an optional attribute is pointless. It contributes to the PSVI, but not to the valid/invalid assessment.